# Read from GPIO Pin on CC2530

Tags: c, microcontroller, sensors, gpio, contiki

I am working on a task to read in the values produced from sensors soldered to the GPIO pins on the cc2530 battery board. Three different type of sensors are soldered onto it ; temperature (analogue, out voltage), Light(analogue, out frequency) and barometer(analogue).

I have been able to successfully read the temperature and display the figures correctly (the example was provided in the contiki git repo) but i am unable to manually configure the GPIO pins to read from the photodiode.

Any help please

```
P0SEL &= ~0x04; /* Set as GPIO */
P0DIR &= ~0x04; /* Set as Input */
P0INP |= 0x04; /* Set as tri-state */
```

Comment: OK, why not create your own example by reading the chip datasheet and OS documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

Here a sample code to read from pin on cc2530 :

```
static void ReadLightSensor(void)
 {
                    //select pin in hex form
        P0SEL &= ~0x10; /* Set pin (sample) as GPIO */
        P0DIR &= ~0x10; /* Set pin as input*/
        P0INP |= 0x10;  /* Set as tri-state*/
        APCFG |= 0x10;  /* configure ADC on pin*/

        ADCCON3 = 0x34; /*This represents the paramters passed into ADCCON3*/

        while (!ADCIF);
        ADCIF = 0;

        tv = ADCL;
        tv |= (((unsigned short) ADCH) << 8);
        tv >>= 4 ;
        lv = tv;
                    PRINTF("Pin reading = 0x%04x\n\r", lv);
```

Comment: I have also noticed an issue when printing the values of the sensor.

Comment: I have also noticed an issue when printing the values of the sensor. The variables ADCL and ADCH contain 8 bit that represent that represent the different parts of the result. Also, from the code the last 4 bits are discard and regarded as noise (from datasheet) hence the 'tv >>= 4' operation. When printing out the values, i print them in a full hex form (0xABCD) which is 16bit. The results I get for the highest intensity level is 0x07FF while the lowest intensity is 0x0FFE. The figures arent quite right. Does anyone have any suggestions please ?